# Sublime Text Config Q

Tags: configuration, sublimetext2

(Running ST2 on Win7)

Just looking into ST2 as an ide for WebDev. I've introduced a few packages, but have got a bit lost in the configuration of them! I've a couple of problems.

Firstly I've got ST2 configured to open the browser on file save, but unfortunately it opens all files rather than just .html files. Ideally I'd like it to live refresh if the js is already in use, but in the worst case, just open .html files  and ignore .js files

Secondly when it opens a .html file it opens it as a file rather than via SublimeServer which is running. I've followed [this](https://github.com/adampresley/sublime-view-in-browser/wiki/Viewing-on-a-Local-Server) link and believe SublimeServer is running on the same port.

Here's the SublimeServer config:

```
{
  "attempts": 5,
  "autorun": true,
  "interval": 500,
  "mimetypes":
  {
    "": "application/octet-stream",
    ".c": "text/plain",
    ".h": "text/plain",
    ".py": "text/plain"
  },
  "port": 8000
}
```

and the proj config

```
{
  "folders":
  [
    {
  "path": "/E/Projects/MyProjects/My.Web/My.Web.App/My.Web.App.Designer"
    }
  ],
  "settings": 
  {
    "sublime-view-in-browser": 
    {
      "baseUrl": "http://localhost:8000/",
      "basePath": "E:\\Projects\\MyProjects\\My.Web\\My.Web.App\\My.Web.App.Designer"
    }
  }
}
```

So where do I need to look in the config to modify this behaviour?

EDIT:

The packages I currently have installed are:

- [Bracket Highlighter](https://github.com/facelessuser/BracketHighlighter)
- [Browser Refresh](https://github.com/gcollazo/BrowserRefresh-Sublime)
- [DocBlockr](https://github.com/Warin/Sublime/tree/master/DocBlockr)
- [Emmet](https://github.com/sergeche/emmet-sublime)
- [Git](https://github.com/kemayo/sublime-text-git)
- [Grunt](https://github.com/tvooo/sublime-grunt)
- [JSLint](https://github.com/fbzhong/sublime-jslint)
- Nodejs
- Package Control
- [Side Bar](https://github.com/titoBouzout/SideBarEnhancements)
- [SublimeCodeIntel](https://github.com/SublimeCodeIntel/SublimeCodeIntel)
- [SublimeLinter](https://github.com/SublimeLinter/SublimeLinter)
- [View in Browser](https://github.com/adampresley/sublime-view-in-browser)
- [Web Inspector](http://sokolovstas.github.io/SublimeWebInspector/)

(and SublimeServer)

I pretty much got them all from Package Control.

As I newbie, I may need to pair some of these back.

Many thx IA

Simon

Comment: can you please list all the plugins you're using, with URLs?

Comment: @MattDMo Matt, just updated the question. Thx for replying.